# Filter Backbone collection and keep original

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

In the following code, I have set up a view where I am filtering a collection based on a date input. The code works correctly the first time, but obviously the collection resets and then if I filter by date again it doesn't filter from the original collection.  What is the best practice to filter collections in backbone and maintain a copy of the original?

```
window.DataIndexView = Backbone.View.extend({  
  tagName: 'section',
  className: 'data',
  events: {
    "click #changedate" : "filterDate"
  },
  initialize: function(){
   _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'filterDate');
   .template = _.template($("#data_template").html());
    this.collection.bind('reset', this.render());
  },
  render: function(){
    var data = this.collection;
    $(this.el).html(this.template({}));

    data.each(function(point){  

    });

    return this;
  },
  filterDate: function() {
    var startdate = this.$("#startdate").val();
    var filtered = _.filter(this.collection, function(item) {
      return moment(item.get("date")).valueOf() > moment(startdate, 'MM-DD-YYYY').valueOf();
    });
    this.collection.reset(filtered);
  }
});
```

Comment: Did any of the answers help you? Would you kindly upvote it, if that's the case? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

_.filter *DOES NOT* touch your collection. it returns a brand new array. You can use it to instantiate a new collection, if you wish.

I believe what you want can be achieved with something like

```
filterDate: function() {
  var startdate = this.$("#startdate").val();
  // Basically a collection clone. It'll keep the same references,
  // instead of copying each object
  this.original_collection = new YourCollectionType(this.collection.models);
  this.collection.reset(_.filter(this.collection, function(item) {
    return moment(item.get("date")).valueOf() > moment(startdate, 'MM-DD-YYYY').valueOf();
  }));
  // Render triggered automagically.
}
```

Comment: Sorry, when I was copying the code over the line this.collection.reset() should have been this.collection.reset(filtered).  The reason why I want to call render again is because there are several functions (not shown) that pull analytics from the new collection.

Comment: Now your request is clear. Answer updated to better assist you.

Answer (score 0):

You should not filter your collection inside the view. A better way is to create a FilteredCollection from your original collection.

### DateFilteredCollection

```
function DateFilteredCollection(original){
    var filtered = new original.constructor();

    filtered.filter = function(startdate){

        var filteredItems = _.filter(this.collection, function(item) {
            return moment(item.get("date")).valueOf() > moment(startdate, 'MM-DD-YYYY').valueOf();
        });

        filtered.reset(filteredItems);
    };

    original.on('reset', function(){
        filtered.reset(original.models);
    });

    return filtered;
}
```

### DataIndexView

```
window.DataIndexView = Backbone.View.extend({  
  tagName: 'section',
  className: 'data',
  events: {
    "click #changedate" : "filterDate"
  },
  initialize: function(){
   _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'filterDate');
   .template = _.template($("#data_template").html());
    this.collection.bind('reset', this.render());
  },
  render: function(){
    var data = this.collection;
    $(this.el).html(this.template({}));

    data.each(function(point){  

    });

    return this;
  },
  filterDate: function() {
    var startdate = this.$("#startdate").val();
    this.collection.filter(startdate); // use filter function here
  }
});
```

### Creating your view

```
var original = new OriginalCollection();  // your original collection
var filteredCollection = DateFilteredCollection( original );
var dataIndexView = new window.DataIndexView({
  collection: filteredCollection
});

original.fetch(); // fetch the data -> filteredCollection will automatically filter it.
```